# VBscript to open text file and search for specific string for network path to copy files

Tags: vbscript

Let me first start off by saying I'm not experienced, but I know a little bit.
I need some help with VBS. I'm trying to create a script that will open a text file, search for a specific string within the file and then cut part string down and use it as a variable.
Let me explain why. I have a text file that has a network path in it. The path will be different from person to person, hence why I need pull this as a value.

```
<setting name="ConfigPathV4" serial="String">
<value>\\ServerName\Foldername</value>
```

The path I need to pull out of the string is

> \\Servername\Foldername

Once I have that path, I need to be able to copy certain file types from the path (XLL,DLL,DNA) to a local folder.

The catch is, I might need to reference this path later in the script as I'm doing way more than just this.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

To read your text file contents

```
Set objFSO = createObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
ObjFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FilePath)
StrText= objFile.ReadAll
ObjFile.close
Set objFile= nothing
```

To extract the path value

```
Set objXML = createObject("msxml2.domdocument")
objXML.LoadXML strText

StrExtractedPath=ObjXML.SelectSingleNode("value").NodeValue
```

To copy files from the path

```
DestFile = "MyFile"
DestPath = "pathToTheDestFile"
SrcFile = "FileToCopy"
ObjFSO.MoveFile(DestPath& DestFile, StrExtractedPath & SrcFile) 'This statement can move most of the file types
```

Garbage collection

```
Set objFSO = nothing
Set objXML = nothing
```

Have typed this answer on phone, so there might be a debugging and syntax correction required